# React + Redux + Firebase: how to deal with a firebase configuration defined and exported as a class?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, redux

I am learning how to add authentication to a React+Firebase project. Previously, when I needed to export my firebase configuration constant, I used to do it like this:

```
const config = {
//...
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config)
const database = firebase.database()
export {database}
```

And then `import {database} from 'path'` where I want to use it.

However, in the new authentication implementation, I have something like this:

```
const config = {
//...
  };

class Firebase {
constructor() {
app.initializeApp(config);

/* Helper */

this.serverValue = app.database.ServerValue;
this.emailAuthProvider = app.auth.EmailAuthProvider;

/* Firebase APIs */

this.auth = app.auth();
this.db = app.database();

//etc
  }

export default Firebase;
```

So in another file, I can now `import Firebase from 'path'` - however I don't know how to access the database of Firebase. Firebase.db and Firebase.database() where not working. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Doubting anyone will have the same question, but here it is:

We are dealing with a class now. So when I export Firebase, I am not exporting it as an object ready to be used (as I used to do) - now I am exporting it as a class.

So when I import it to another file: `import Firebase from 'path'` I have to remember to create an instance of it in that file to be able to use it.

```
import Firebase from 'path'  //Firebase is not an object, it is a class

const fbInstance = new Firebase(); //creating an instance of the class

const database = fbInstance.db;  //each instance is assigned a db (database) through the constructor (posted earlier)
```

Review some OOP (or javascript classes) if you didn't quite understand this.